# Can someone help me why my program is printing a random number?

Tags: c

I am learning to code in C and I need to create a program which sorts out numbers in an array by even numbers first and then the uneven. The numbers don't have to be sorted smallest to largest. The first entered numbers is supposed to be the size of the array. I managed to figure it out but one number is always missing and presented with a random number. Am i missing something ?

```
int a[101], a2[101], i, j, n, k = 0;
scanf ("%d", &n);

for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
scanf ("%d", &a[i]);

for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    if (a[i]%2 == 0)
        {
        if (a[i] == 0)
            {
                a2[k] = a[i];
                k++;
                continue;
            }
        a2[k] = a[i];
        k++;
        }
}


for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    if (a[i]%2 != 0)
    {
        a2[k] = a[i];
        k++;
    }
}


for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    printf ("%d ", a2[i]);


return 0;
```

I enter the following numbers:

6

1 3 2 5 8 10

I should get:
2 8 10 1 3 5

What I'm getting:
2 8 10 1 3 508

I tried with other combinations too, problem persists but with different number.

Comment: Did you check that `k == n` at the end?

Comment: I dont get the `if (a[i] == 0)` check....why is it there?

Comment: what happens if you add a `printf("\n");` just before the `return 0;` ?

Comment: BTW, `j` is never used,

Comment: cannot reproduce: https://ideone.com/qdELsO

Comment: @SanderDeDycker That's a good point. kasa - why dont you try that?

Comment: Why do you increment the position and then continue when `a[i]` is 0 ? I ran your code and it's give me the correct result.

Comment: Are you sure the `08` at the end isn't printed by something else? Please show a complete program that can be compiled and shows this result.

Comment: I just added a `puts("")` before `return 0`;

Comment: All output streams to open files are flushed on normal program termination. The need for a newline is when debugging to ensure the buffer was flushed if the program subsequently crashes.

Comment: @WeatherVane : 1) the OP hasn't indicated whether the `return 0;` ends the program, so there might be more output after it. 2) a flush without a newline does not guarantee the (full) line will be written out to a text stream (that's implementation defined). 3) the newline also serves as a separator between the output of this code, and whatever output follows it (eg. a command prompt).

Comment: I added the 0 check as a precaution, I deleted it now. I'm also a noob :) Anyways, I'm required to work in Codeblocks for this and all i did was copy the code, and paste it in new file. I don't know why, but the code works great now. Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Checked your code several time its written well and worked well too. The extra **08** after **5** may be printed by something else. You can use a newline after printing all the element of **ara2** to make sure the **08** is printed form any element of **ara2** or not. like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    printf ("%d ", a2[i]);
printf("\n");
```

And one more thing. There are no need to add the bellow portion in your code. The code will work same even if you don't add this.

```
    if (a[i] == 0)
        {
            a2[k] = a[i];
            k++;
            continue;
        }
```

Happy Coding.